# Saving changed clip into file

Tags: java, audio, javasound

How can I save an opened audio file with changed volume?

I trying this:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("some_file.wav"));

Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

gainControl.setValue(-30.0f); // Reduce volume by 10 decibels.
File file = new File("new.wav");
AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);
```

But this is saving an empty file.

Comment: `gainControl.setValue(-30.0f);` This only relates to how the current `Clip` is **played**. It does not change the actual data of the sound.

Comment: .. plus, it's likely the input stream will have been entirely read, and the read pointer set at the final byte, after the `Clip` has read it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet will be to take the bytes from the AudioInputStream and convert them to PCM values, then multiply the PCM values by a factor that matches -10 db. I don't know what that factor would be. Then convert back to bytes and write that.

The first code example in the tutorial [Using Files and Format Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html) shows a while loop where the conversions would take place, at the comment: "// Here, do something useful with the audio..."

The prior tutorial on the Audio Trail: "Processing Audio with Controls" might also be helpful, but the built-in controls are limited and dependent on the host computer and OS. For example, if you want to change volumes (put in a fade-in or fade-out) the control lines probably don't work very well due to the granularity being tied to the size of the audio buffer. So I recommend the advice of the final paragraphs of the "Processing Audio with Controls" tutorial, the section "Manipulating the Audio Data Directly".